# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:null constraint

Tags: java, spring

I have this student class in model package in my model pacakage it has userid which refrences the userid in user class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id
@Column(name = "Libraryid")
private int libraryid;
@Column(name = "Stdphone")
private String phoneno;
@Column(name = "stdmail")
private String studentmail;
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
@Column(name = "academicsid")
private int academicid;
@Column(name = "user_userid", nullable = true)
private int userid;
@Column(name = "stdname")
private String studentname;

public String getStudentname() {
    return studentname;
}

public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
    this.studentname = studentname;
}

public int getLibraryid() {
    return libraryid;
}

public void setLibraryid(int libraryid) {
    this.libraryid = libraryid;
}

public String getPhoneno() {
    return phoneno;
}

public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
    this.phoneno = phoneno;
}

public String getStudentmail() {
    return studentmail;
}

public void setStudentmail(String studentmail) {
    this.studentmail = studentmail;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getAcademicid() {
    return academicid;
}

public void setAcademicid(int academicid) {
    this.academicid = academicid;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

}
```

This is the jsp file  for adding the student in the database  but i have not put the userid  because i want to enter when signup student for the system

```
<body>
<form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="student"  action="admin">
    <table>

    <tr>
            <td><form:label path="libraryid">libraryid</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="libraryid" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="studentname">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="studentname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="phoneno">phoneno</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="phoneno" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="studentmail">studentmail</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="studentmail" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="academicid">academicid</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="academicid" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form:form>
```

In the controller package in the admincontroller class i have this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student) {

    sDao.addStudent(student);
    return "home";
}
```

And i have this error

```
  message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sunwaylib`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `fk_student_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`Userid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE); SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sunwaylib`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `fk_student_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`Userid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

although I have set the database allow null value[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uukwW.png)

Comment: There is any constraints on database level between student and user table?

Comment: yes there is the  student table has userid which refrences userid primary key in usertable